# How can I update a surrogate key based on an older entry of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, data-warehouse

I have a table called player_stage.
I am trying to prepare my data so I can put it into a data warehouse.

I currently have a unreliable work-around that involves a duplicates view and handpicking the values from the duplicates.

I need to create a query that gives duplicates the same surrogate key(sk).

Any idea how I can do this? I've been stuck on t
his for 3 days.

[image]

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  A better explanation of the logic to implement would also help.  And how do you define duplicate?  I don't see any duplicates in your sample data.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @GordonLinoff See John McDonald for a duplicate.

Comment: This is the result that I want, I just don't know how to design it. The logic is the following. If the players from different sources have the same name, it means it's the same player. In my case it's Tiger Woods and John McDonald. These players need to have the same surrogate key.  My steps are the following: add players1 to players_stage,  give them SKs; add players2 to players_stage, give them if they are not already in the table. I am trying to find a consistent way to give surrogate keys to the duplicates.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . They have different player ids.  Why should I think they are duplicates?

Comment: If you check the expected `SK` values for the McDonald records, they have the same value.  Anyway, all this talk about McDonald is making me hungry.  I'm going for an egg McMuffin now, see you later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `DENSE_RANK` can work here:

```
SELECT
    PLAYER_ID,
    PLAYER_NAME,
    DB_SOURCE,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PLAYER_NAME) SK
FROM yourTable;
```

The above call to `DENSE_RANK` would assign the same `SK` value to all records belonging to the same player name.

If you are using a version of MySQL earlier than 8+, then we can simulate the dense rank with user variables, e.g.

```
SELECT t1.PLAYER_ID, t1.PLAYER_NAME, t1.DB_SOURCE, t2.rn AS SK
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PLAYER_NAME, @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PLAYER_NAME FROM yourTable) t, (SELECT @rn := 0) r
    ORDER BY PLAYER_NAME
) t2
    ON t1.PLAYER_NAME = t2.PLAYER_NAME
ORDER BY
    t1.PLAYER_ID;
```

### Demo